# Menu en ventana sin bordes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Verán tengo este código para generar un programa sin bordes en PyQt5 el problema esta en la barra de menú.

Lo primero que intente fue directamente cargar el menú principal con la función menuBar(), pero no logro acomodar los botones de cerrar, minimizar y maximizar en la ubicacion típica de una ventana.

Y en este ejemplo lo hice con un frame y dentro del frame cargar los botones y programarlos con las funciones(close,maximized, etc ). Pero el problema es que el frame se mantiene del mismo tamaño y no crece a la par del mainWindow.

Alguna solución:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication,QMenuBar
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)
        self.setWindowFlags((Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
       #Boton de cerrado
        self.bclose.clicked.connect(self.close)
       #Frame superior que actua como menu
        self.f1
       #Boton de archivo
        self.Archivo

def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
        event.accept()


def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
        event.accept()


app = QApplication([]) 
d = Main()
d.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: donde esta el frame? tu codigo no es reproducible, por favor provee un [mcve]

Comment: Aquí esta el link del script y de la interfaz Pyqt [https://mega.nz/#F!eMVkxRyI!eUzqxaPgDrRFZ9uKr4V3eA]